# Swift - zip/unzip Data in memory without any file system interaction

Tags: swift, macos, zip, foundation, zipfoundation

My code needs to parse heaps of JSON files, and those files are hosted on GitHub and only available bundled as 1 single ZIP file. Because the ZIP file is only about 80 MB, I want to keep the entire unzipping operation in memory.

I'm able to load the ZIP file into memory as a `Data?` variable, but I'm not able to find a way to unzip a `Data` variable in memory and then assign the unzipped file/data to some other variables. I've tried using [ZIP Foundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation), but its `Archive` type's initializers take only file URLs. I didn't try [Zip](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip), but its documentation shows that it takes file URLs as well.

Here is my code:

```swift
import Cocoa
import Alamofire

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let zipURL = URL(string: "https://github.com/KSP-CKAN/CKAN-meta/archive/master.zip")!

        AF.request(zipURL).validate().responseData { response in
            var zipData: Data? = response.data
            //  Here I want to unzip `zipData` after unwrapping it.
        }
    }

}
```

I also looked into passing a `Data` variable off as a file, but failed to find a way to do it.

---

**UPDATE** (2019-12-01 05:00)

According to [this pull request thread](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation/pull/143) on ZIPFoundation, the feature I'm looking for will be included in the next release. I tried to use [the feature's contributor's fork](https://github.com/microtherion/ZIPFoundation/tree/Memory_Archive_v2), but somehow Swift Package Manager wouldn't allow it.

Before finding this, I tried using Python's `zipfile` library through Swift-Python interoperability provided by [PythonKit](https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit), but it didn't work out, because Foundation's `Data` in Swift can not be cast into a `PythonObject` type.

Apple's [Compression framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression) also looked promising, but it seems to have a soft limit of 1 MB on compressed files. The compressed file I need is about 80 MB, way larger than 1 MB.

So far, ZIPFoundation is my most hopeful solution.

---

**UPDATE** (2019-12-01 06:00)

On another try, I was able to install [microtherion's fork](https://github.com/microtherion/ZIPFoundation/tree/Memory_Archive_v2) through Swift Package Manager. The following code should work:

```swift
import Cocoa
import Alamofire
import ZIPFoundation

... //  ignoring irrelevant parts of the code


    let zipURL = URL(string: "https://github.com/KSP-CKAN/CKAN-meta/archive/master.zip")!

    AF.request(zipURL).validate().responseData { response in

        //  a Data variable that holds the raw bytes
        var zipData: Data? = response.data

        //  an Archive instance created with the Data variable
        var zipArchive = Archive(data: zipData!, accessMode: .read)

        //  iterate over the entries in the Archive instance, and extract each entry into a Data variable
        for entry in zipArchive! {
            var unzippedData: Data
            do {
                _ = try zipArchive?.extract(entry) {unzippedData($0)}
            } catch {
                ...
            }
            ...
        }

    }
```

Comment: Create a local resource fileURL (can be located at a temporary folder), write your data there and unzip the fileURL.

Comment: @LeoDabus While the approach you suggested will ultimately work, the point of my question is to find a way to skip the intermediary file I/O and keep everything in memory.

Comment: Note that depending on the size of your zip dats your app might crash out of memory

Comment: @LeoDabus I think I found a solution to my problem, and I updated the description accordingly. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Can you share some code how you can get value in a String from memory